# Jacoco Plugin not working After upgrading to Spring Boot 2.7.10

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, sonarqube, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am trying to take out sonar coverage of my code but the coverage is coming as 0 %. Earlier, tests were also coming as 0 , but it got resolved after adding junit-vintage-engine library. But the code coverage issue is still unresolved.This is the plugin that I have added

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.8.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jacoco-site</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Surefire reports are generating, but I am also getting this warning in pom file.:

> Plugin could not be resolved. Ensure the plugin's groupId, artifactId
> and version are present.
>
> Additional information: Unable to resolve
> org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin

But when I exceute mvn clean install, jar file is generated but it is not downloading jacoco plugin.Also, no jacoco files are created in target folder.